# Should you store current application state in a database?

Tags: database, architecture, state

I have started working on a project where a Postgres database is used as an integral component in the system architecture. This has forced me to abandon my previous notions that a database is well, to store things.

There is an API which translates incoming requests into database queries/updates. This causes triggers in the database to then notify another application to update the actual system accordingly.

To me this all seems unnecessary. This is also in a fairly system critical architecture, and yet we have no way to guarantee knowledge of the underlying systems failure making it back up the chain since everything is Async. In short I don't like it at all. My view is we should restart from scratch immediately using direct communication between the API and the underlying system, using the database only to store persistant state updates / user information etc.

What i'm really looking for here is someone to explain to me why I'm wrong before I end up falling out with the team, but all views are welcome.

Comment: Bit difficult to know why its architected like that with out knowing the relevant requirements. There must be some reason - even if misguided - why its done that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason to support such integration is its low cost, especially if two integrated systems uses own proprietry technologies comminucating bad with each other. Also, DB integration presents old style of integration.

What you want to acheive (or at least increase) is called "autonomy". It is too big topic to talk about, but I'll try to highlight most important things according to your situation.

1. Triggers and stored procedures are almost always evil. It always leads to "logic leak" to DB and hence results in bad portability and maintainability of busines logic and whole app. The only thing stored procedures may be usefull is for increasing of performance. But there are many ways to tune performance without them.
2. As soon as your applications are connected via DB you are dealing with tight coupling between them, thus they are tightly depend on each other and hence maintainability and reusability of both applications suffer.
3. By connecting of applications via DB in some complex manner you may also stuck with scaling in future.
4. Using DB solution for invokation of something you are dealing with coupling to technology, which is not designed to do that. Thus it's bad because of inflexibility and possible future limitations. Its more poorly if some non-standardized of proprietary tools and protocols are used.

Today (enterprise) best practice is in using of fully autonomous applications with application (not integration) non-shared database, communicating via standardized protocol, probably through some reliable middleware. It is more expensive but it provides lots of benefits (scalability, maintainability, flexibility, etc).

To decide if you are actually should rewrite something, at first you need to estimate costs and benefits. If it is a big legacy tightly coupled composition which works fine, than probably it's better way not to touch it, but create Facade-like wrapper if needed.

Finally,

> What i'm really looking for here is someone to explain to me why I'm
>   wrong

I don't think you are wrong.